# Plot the search volume over time

Tags: python

> Plot the search volume over time. Verify that your result looks similar to [THIS](http://www.google.dk/trends/explore#q=android,%20iphone)

First, I should import some data and print the 2 first lines. I did that successfully, but I can't figure out how to do the question above?

So far my code looks like this:

```
import csv

with open('iphonevsandroid.csv', 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for i in range(2):
        print reader.next()

N=2
f=open('iphonevsandroid.csv', 'rb')
for i in range(N):
    line=f.next().strip()
    print line
f.close()
```

Comment: Your question is very unclear as to what you're actually asking. Could you please edit it to add more detail?

Answer (score 0):

You can use pygame to plot the data.

A short example:

```
import pygame,sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,32)
lines = list(zip(data,data[1::]))

while True:
    screen.fill((255,255,255))
    for x,(start,end) in enumerate(lines):
        pygame.draw.line(screen,(0,0,0),(x*50,start),((x+1)*50,end)
    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```